# How to solve $x^{\prime\prime\prime} + 2x^{\prime\prime} - x = e^{-t}\cos(2t)$ using the operator method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I did
 $(D^3 + 2D - 1)x = e^{-t}\cos(2t) \Rightarrow x = \frac{1}{D^3 + 2D - 1}e^{-t}\cos(2t) \Rightarrow x= \frac{e^{-t}}{(D-1)^3 + 2(D-1) - 1}\cos(2t) \Rightarrow$ 
$x =\frac{e^{-t}}{D^3-3D^2+3D-1+2D-2-1}\cos(2t) = \frac{e^{-t}}{D^3-3D^2+5D-4}\cos(2t)$, but I'm having trouble with $D^3-3D^2+5D-4$.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(D^3 + 2D^2 - 1)x = e^{-t}\cos(2t) 
$$
 $$ \implies x_p = \frac{1}{D^3 + 2D^2 - 1}e^{-t}\cos(2t) $$

You forget the power D for the operator. You have $D^3$ and $D^2$.
$$\implies x_p =e^{-t} \frac{1}{(D-1)^2(D+1)  - 1}\cos(2t)$$
$$\implies x_p =e^{-t} \frac{1}{(-2D-3)(D+1)  - 1}\cos(2t)$$
$$ x_p =e^{-t} \frac{1}{(-5D+4)}\cos(2t)$$
$$ x_p =e^{-t} \frac{(5D+4)}{116}\cos(2t)$$
Finally:
$$ \boxed { x_p =e^{-t} \frac{(-5 \sin(2t)+2 \cos(2t))}{58}}$$

Comment: Thanks for your help @Aryadeva

Comment: You're welcome...You can use that property for even power of D...like $D^2$ @Kira  You can check here the answer given by WA https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%27%27+%2B+2x%27%27-+x+%3D+e%5E%28-t%29cos%282t%29

Comment: One more question, how did you go from $ x_p =e^{-t} \frac{1}{(-5D+4)}\cos(2t)$ to
$ x_p =e^{-t} \frac{(5D+4)}{116}\cos(2t)$?

Comment: No probelm you can ask any question you want... We cant eliminate the D at the denominator since it's not an even power.. So we multiply the fraction by $5D+4$ then we calculate the value at the denominator since now we have $ -(25D^2-16)$ this gives us the $116$ @Kira

Comment: Right, thanks! :)

Comment: Glad you got it ...@Kira